# como subir archivos a drive

Tags: jquery, css, html5

yo estoy programando un repositorio los usuarios adjuntan su documento, depuesque ya este adjunto quiero que se pueda abrir con word online o google doc y que se pueda editar directamente de la pagina. como se puede hacer esto? gracias

Comment: Con `Google Docs` se puede, pero hasta donde yo se, el archivo debe estar en `Google Docs (o Drive)` para poder embeberlo y editarlo.

Comment: sii eso ya lo se el problema es que no se como subir los archivos al drive automaticamente por favor me puede explicar gracias

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, que esa es otra pregunta, considera crear una nueva pregunta o edita esta. Te dejo este enlace [sobre como subir archivos a Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads)